# join chat room and send/receive messages

Tags: join, xmpp, openfire, strophe, chatroom

I can not find manual *How join to chat room and send/receive messages ?*

I use Strophe + openFire.

How I send message:

```
var o = {from : 'test2@xmpp.local/5c5d4956', to:'1@conference.xmpp.local', type : 'groupchat', xmlns : Strophe.NS.MUC};
var m = $msg(o);
m.c('body', null, 'body text'); 
connection.send(m.tree());
```

How I receive:

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
<message xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc" from="1@conference.xmpp.local" to="test2@xmpp.local/77ce8c0e" type="error">            <body>dfsdfsdfsd</body><error xmlns="" code="406" type="modify"><not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></message></body>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Join to room :**

```
var o = {to:'roomName@conference.domain.com/youNick'}; 
var m = $pres(o); 
m.c('x', {xmlns : 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'}, null); 
connection.send(m.tree());
```

or if need enter password

```
var o = {to:'roomName@conference.domain.com/youNick'}; 
var m = $pres(o); 
m.c('x', {xmlns : 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'}, null).c('password', null, 'pass'); 
connection.send(m.tree());
```

**Send message in room :**

```
var o = {to:'roomName@conference.domain.com', type : 'groupchat'}; 
var m = $msg(o); m.c('body', null, 'hello'); 
connection.send(m.tree());
```

Comment: The important part of this is `/youNick`; you need to send a nickname in the to address of the presence you use to join.

Comment: If i have 2 devices under the same user to join a group(2 users, 3 devices), and person 1 send message to person2, the message would send out to all 3 devices right? Each device will have their own nickname?